# Delete parse class and object in class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, delete-row

I try to delete a class called "test". I found some code but nothing happens. The class are still exist.

```
-(void)delete{
PFObject *deleteClass = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"test"];
[deleteClass deleteEventually];
}
```

Error message:

Failed to run command eventually with error: Error Domain=Parse Code=106 "(null)" UserInfo={message=Failed to run an eventually command., exception=Attempt to delete non-existent object.}

Comment: Are there any objects of this class in storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit 1: After looking through more Parse forums, I've found [a definitive answer](https://parse.com/questions/how-do-i-drop-a-class-programmatically) stating that you cannot do this with the Parse SDK; you must use the Parse website.*

From [this question](https://www.parse.com/questions/delete-classes-from-dashboard) on the Parse website, it looks like this should be done from your Parse dashboard. If you are constantly creating and deleting new classes and need to do this dynamically, I'm not sure you are using Parse in the way it was intended.